# Constructing joint confidence intervals/multiple confidence intervals

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, confidence-interval

Consider $n$ iid observations $X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n$ from a $Uniform(a,b)$ distribution, where $a$ and $b$ are both unknown. How do we construct a joint confidence interval for $(a,b)$?

I would prefer a rectangular shape confidence interval, which can be obtained by using Bonferroni's method, so I guess the question can also be reformed as: How do we get a confidence interval for $a$?

Comment: Using the minimum observation $X_{(1)}$ and maximum observation  $X_{(n)}$  you can estimate $a$ and $b$ with $X_{(1)}-k(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})$ and  $X_{(n)}+k(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})$ for some $k$.  In effect you then want an interval for $k$, which will depend on $n$.

Comment: @Henry, I guess you mean $(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})/k$? Also, I didn't get what you said in the end, I was trying to get CI for $a$, can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Whether you do multiplication or division makes little difference.  As an example, with $n=100$, you might decide a reasonable interval for a multiplicative $k$ might be about $[0.000126, 0.0453]$.  So if your observations had a minimum of $2000$ and a maximum of $3000$, this might give a confidence interval for $a$ of about $[1954.7, 1999.874]$ and for $b$ of about $[3000.126, 3045.3]$.  Simulation (with $n=100$) suggests that the confidence interval for $a$ will be completely below  $a$ about $1.25\%$ of the time and completely above $a$ about $1.25\%$ of the time, and similarly for $b$...

Comment: ... while the combined confidence intervals for $a$ and $b$ will contain $a$ and $b$ between $95\%$ and $95.1\%$ of the time.  As far as I can tell, for large $n$, a suitable $k$ is roughly inversely proportional to $n$

Comment: Alternatively, you might prefer an single tailed interval for $k$ such as about $[0, 0.0379]$.  Repeating the example this would give  $[1962.1, 2000]$ for $a$ and $[3000,3037.9]$ for $b$, with the confidence interval for $a$ being completely above $a$ about $2.5\%$ of the time, and  the combined confidence intervals for $a$ and $b$ containing $a$ and $b$ between $95\%$ and $95.1\%$ of the time.

Comment: @Henry, Oh I misunderstood your $k$, I meant  $(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})/n$. It makes sense to translate the problem into a CI in $k$, but I didn't get how do you derive a CI for $k$.

Comment: I simulated a million examples and looked at the empirical distribution of $k$

Comment: I see, it wasn't derivation then

Comment: But certainly suggests results of one.

Comment: Haha, that's true